# Users database table scenario. Good or bad?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got a table `users` which also has a column `active` that is either 0 or 1. And a `activation_keys` table that stores the activation keys for newly registered inactive user (where active == 0).

All the users that register for a new account will start off inactive and will always have a matching relational row in the `activation_keys` table. If a user activates his/her account, the relational row is removed from the `activation_keys` table and active is set to 1 for that user in the users table.

But now I want to also be able to disable users by setting active to 0. And to distinguish a newly registered user that still needs to activate his account and a user that's disabled, I'll be checking if there is a relational activation key in the `activation_keys` table. If there is, that means the user is not disabled. If there isn't, it means that the user is disabled and should not have access to his account.

Is the way I just described a good way to handle it?

Also, I would end up with a mixture of disabled and active users in the `users` table. Is that fine, or should I remove the disabled users to another table specifically for that? Any user that gets disabled, will be disabled permanently.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: In my opinion, disabled and active users in the same table is absolutely fine. If the activation Keys table simply holds a single column for an activation key, then it might be simpler to just store the activation key as a column in the user table and set it to null or empty once consumed. It will mean one less join in your queries. Even if it is a couple of columns, unless space is a major issue I would still be inclined to store them in the same table, rather than having a one to one relationship with two tables.

Comment: @GarethD Isn't it a bad thing to have empty fields in a record?

Comment: You could extend the activation table to multiple use, something like, `id, user_id, key, action, ts_created, ts_used`, on `action` it would be something like `activation`, `reactivation`, `temporary password`, etc. This way you will be able to keep track of when the user activated his account, if he lost a password and requested a new one and when it was used it or expire if a key has been up longer than X amount of time and so on.

Comment: I am aware of the school of thought that empty fields are bad, but I (mostly) don't buy into it, although there are exceptions to most rules. Storage is a concern when I am designing a database, but my primary concerns are efficiency and ease of use. I am not sure of the scale of the application, but every little helps, so doing the extra lookup for every hit on the users table would be more of a concern to me than the extra bit per row when it is not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually just use a "status" column where I store if the user is "active", "waiting for activation" or "disabled".

But there are always many ways of accomplishing the task, I think there is nothing really wrong with your approach, but it might be better to seperate the activation logic (`activation_keys` table) and disabling of users, since you might want - at a later point - maybe add some re-activation or something similar also for disabled users.

Comment: I like that. So I could have something like status is 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: Absolutely right! And maybe in a seperate table entries for 0 -> waiting, 1 -> activated, 2 -> disabled, ... which also allows you to add states later on, if need be.